# How to implement display:table div with additional, merged row?

Tags: html, css

Table contains rows that have some simple, short data cells and wide and long one that has to be under each row, describing the values above. This row/cell has to have 100% of table width. I have created a [snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/wfzpd6v3/) which can be an example what I have to achieve. I can't create another row though, because the data is generated in one `table-row` div and that is  a requirement as well. Any ideas how to do this? Thanks in advance!

```css
.table {
  display: table;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.row {
  display: table-row;
}

.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.more-info {
  // ? What has to be done here to display this div below 
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">
      Cell 1
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      Cell 2
    </div>

    <div class="more-info">
      More info. This row should display BELOW this row.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">
      Cell 1
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      Cell 2
    </div>

    <div class="more-info">
      More info. This row should display BELOW this row.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You mean like a table's `rowspan` attribute? That is not possible in CSS, sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Display:flex;` can do the job for you, `display:table;` **can not**.

```css
.table {
  width: 200px; /* because you did set width:100px to cells like containers */
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.cell {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.more-info {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">
      Cell 1
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      Cell 2
    </div>

    <div class="more-info">
      More info. This row should display BELOW this row.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">
      Cell 1
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      Cell 2
    </div>

    <div class="more-info">
      More info. This row should display BELOW this row.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Damn...beat me to it...I'd done the demo and was just about to post. - https://jsfiddle.net/wfzpd6v3/1/

Comment: @Paulie_D great minds always meet :), it's a french saying

Comment: This is the answer :) I can't do it in `display:table`. Many thanks!